# I am trying to send.keys a value that I calculated and then click the save button but the value isn't saving, why is this?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

The value I want to calculate is being calculated properly, and the value is being sent and I can see it being typed, but when I click the save button, the value isn't saving.

When I go back to look at the value it isn't there.

How do I change this?

**Correction** - it saves some times but it doesn't other times, I don't get it.

Comment: Relevant HTML, Code trials, Error (if any)?

Comment: Yes.. you have to post your code here and describe your problem in detail, so that somebody is able to help you...

Comment: Lots of things can be happening here. What code runs after you click save? Are you closing the browser? This could be interrupting the save. But we cannot tell what the problem is here until you post relevant code.